# How to have more workers on vue build?

Tags: vue.js, webpack

Right now when I build my vue project using the vue/cli, is very slow.

How to set more worker to work on the build process?

Right now I have only one..

[image]

Comment: Should be [Vue CLI: Parallel](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#parallel)